# Thread C++.Потоки С++. Ошибка "отсутствуют экземпляры конструктора "std::thread::thread", соответствующие списку аргументов

Tags: c++, многопоточность

```
void GA::Start(){
int thr = thread::hardware_concurrency();
thread* th;
th = new thread[thr];
int newpop = population / thr;
do
{

    for (int i = 0; i < newpop; i++)
    {
        th[0] = thread(StartDraw, 4*i);// Ошибка (функция void GA::StartDraw(int i) )
        for (int j = 1; j < thr; j++)
        {
            th[j] = thread(StartNoDraw, 4 * i+j);// Ошибка (функция void GA::StartNoDraw(int i) )
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < thr; j++)
        {
            th[j].join();
        }


    }
```

---

А это пример который сделал, чтобы разобраться и он рабочий

```
thread *th;
th = new thread[thread::hardware_concurrency()];



for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        if (j%4==0) {
            fun(i, j);
        }
        if (j % 4 == 1) {
            th[0] = thread(fun, i, j);
        }
        if (j % 4 == 2) {
            th[1] = thread(fun, i, j);
        }
        if (j % 4 == 3) {
            th[2]=thread(fun,i, j);
        }
    //  th1.join();


    }
    for(int j=0; j<3;j++)
            th[j].join();


}
```

Comment: Покажите `Start[No]Draw`...

Comment: `void GA::StartNoDraw(int i) {<br/>
 while (game[i].getAlive())<br/>
 {<br/>


  Sensor(i);<br/>
  ForwardFeed(i);<br/>
  game[i].Input(max());<br/>
  game[i].Logic();<br/>
 }<br/>
    }`

Comment: Ну вот и ответ - это же не свободная функция! Для **какого** объекта вы ее намерены вызывать?...

Comment: функция где находится ошибка находится в этом же классе void `GA::Start(){..`

Comment: Какая разница, в этом же или не в этом же? У функции `GA::StartNoDraw` **два** параметра: `this` и `i`. А вы передаете только один. И почему вы поместили код функции в комментарий, а не в вопрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот минимальный пример, как надо

```
struct A
{
    void doit(int j)
    {
    }
    void rundo()
    {
        auto t = thread(&A::doit, this, 5);
    }
};
```

Т.е. помимо указания класса функции, передавайте еще и `this`.